# Dolphin takes a while to open (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin, plasma-5

I tried out kubuntu a few months ago and encountered the same problem, when I try to open dolphin it takes about 15 seconds to fully load (this has never happened with any other file manager on other distributions) my PC isn't quite the NASA machine but I'm pretty sure it can do a lot better than this. I'm kinda new at this type of thing so if I'm missing something extremely obvious I apologize lol thanks in advance. Oh and I already tried to unable the "upower service" like it says right here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#Dolphin_and_File_Dialogs_are_extremely_slow_to_start but still no luck